# Get Magento quote totals in base currency

Tags: php, magento, shopping-cart, currency, magento-1.8

Is there a way to get the quote/cart totals in the base currency from a Mage_Sales_Model_Quote object?

Ideally something like getTotals() but with the base currency instead of the user's selected currency.

This is a single store, multiple currencies site.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** example code for what I've tried -

```
// value - 1917.47
$value = $observer->getEvent()->getCart()->getQuote()->getTotals()['grand_total']; 

// localCurr - "EUR"
$localCurr = Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseCurrencyCode(); 

// baseCurr - "GBP"
$baseCurr = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode(); 

Mage::helper('directory')->currencyConvert($value, $localCurr, $baseCurr);
```

This results in an error like

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getCode() on a non-object in <..>\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Directory\Model\Currency.php on line 194
```

**Edit 2:** I saw this which seems to generate the same kind of error, but my currencies do exist in the backend

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3547/programmatically-converting-currency

Comment: show your code, what you have tried?

Comment: @DRAJI - I've updated the question with an example

Comment: I think, above error isn't part of ur given code. please check getCode() method object

Comment: @DRAJI - Yeah, I see that, but that's part of the base Magento install, so I shouldn't change that. The weird thing is that if I switch $localCurr and $baseCurr around it doesn't cause an error

Comment: are you using getCode() for getting base currency code?

Comment: @DRAJI - updated the initial question again with some more of the actual code. I've verified that the values in the comments are actually what is generated by the functions

Comment: $value = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal(); try this one for getting cart page total value

Comment: @DRAJI - That causes the same error

Comment: check with echo $value before getting current currency code and put exit command. you can find where is that error come from

Comment: @DRAJI - I did that already, 

I did die(json_encode(array($value, $localCurr, $baseCurr))); after they were all set and I got [1917.47,"EUR","GBP"]

Comment: you mean, so the error is coming from currency conversion coding....?

Comment: or check with static value, I mean like this  Mage::helper('directory')->currencyConvert('50', 'EUR', 'GBP');

Comment: @DRAJI - Yeah, it's coming from the conversion. Also doing it statically doesn't work either

Comment: I think, it may be problem with any assigned that value. echo Mage::helper('directory')->currencyConvert($value, $localCurr, $baseCurr); or $CC=Mage::helper('directory')->currencyConvert($value, $localCurr, $baseCurr);

Comment: @DRAJI - that doesn't work because the function errors.